# Why should you assign NA to empty prototypes instead of leaving it as empty?

Tags: r, r-s4

While discussing [S4 prototypes](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/S4.html), Hadley states that

> An empty value for age is probably not what you want

Instead, he sets a default value to `NA`. Here is the code

```
setClass("Person", representation(name = "character", age = "numeric"))
```

To access slots of an S4 object you use @, not $:

```
hadley <- new("Person", name = "Hadley")
hadley@age
# numeric(0)
```

**An empty value for age is probably not what you want**, so you can also assign a default prototype for the class:

```
setClass("Person", representation(name = "character", age = "numeric"), 
  prototype(name = NA_character_, age = NA_real_))
hadley <- new("Person", name = "Hadley")
hadley@age
# [1] NA
```

**What are the advantages of setting a `NA` prototype instead of leaving it empty?**

Doesn't it only affect the way you check for whether the slot has a non default value? i.e. `length(hadley@age) == 0` vs `is.na(hadley@age)`?

Comment: One reason that I could think of is that computations with `NA`s give `NA` by default. Assume that you add the following code using your first definition of `Person`: `Alex<-new("Person", name = "Alex",age=99);
mean(unlist(lapply(list(hadley,Alex),function(person) person@age)));`. It could be that you incorrectly infer that the average age in your sample is `99`, whereas you do not know Hadley's age...

Comment: That is a very good reason!

Comment: Can you post it as an answer please?

Answer (score 1):

One reason that I could think of is that computations with `NA`s give `NA` by default. Assume that you add the following code using your first definition of Person

```
#your first definition of Person
setClass("Person", representation(name = "character", age = "numeric"))
hadley <- new("Person", name = "Hadley")
#new Person
Alex<-new("Person", name = "Alex",age=99)
#calculate mean age of two Persons
mean(unlist(lapply(list(hadley,Alex),function(person) person@age)))
#99
```

It could be that you incorrectly infer that the average age in your sample is `99`, whereas you do not know Hadley's age.

For the second definition of Person you would get `NA`

```
setClass("Person", representation(name = "character", age = "numeric"), 
  prototype(name = NA_character_, age = NA_real_))
hadley <- new("Person", name = "Hadley")
Alex<-new("Person", name = "Alex",age=99)
mean(unlist(lapply(list(hadley,Alex),function(person) person@age)))
#NA
```